# Display an object based on its value in Vue

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to display the content of an array object in a modal based on its id and the value of its status.

For example, there are three statuses available; completed, pending, and completed. Each election is recorded with its unique ID with the different status that applies. However, I noticed that all the elections appear as results instead of the particular object I want which is the one with the completed status.

Let's say:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      elections: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "State Elections",
          tier: "Alpha State",
          fromTime: "09:00 pm",
          toTime: "11:00 am",
          date: "2020-06-01",
          status: "completed",
          numQualified: "200",
          numVotes: "157",
          candidates: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "John",
              votes: "80%",
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              deckname: "Fred",
              votes: "30%",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "City Elections",
          tier: "Beta City",
          fromTime: "09:00 pm",
          toTime: "11:00 am",
          date: "2020-06-01",
          status: "ongoing",
          numQualified: "120",
          numVotes: null,
          candidates: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "Chris",
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "Josh",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "President Elections",
          tier: "HQ",
          fromTime: "09:00 pm",
          toTime: "11:00 am",
          date: "2020-08-01",
          status: "pending",
          numQualified: "120",
          numVotes: null,
          candidates: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "Stone",
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "Ben",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
```

Now let's say we only want to display a particular ID with the `status: "completed"`.

```
    <Teleport to="body" v-for="election in displayResult" :key="election.status" :election="completed">
  <modal :show="resultModal" @close="resultModal = false">
    <template #header>
      <h3 class="font-bold">Election Results</h3>
    </template>
    <template #body>
      <div class="inline-flex space-x-2 align-middle">
        <h3 class="font-normal text-md">{{ election.title }}</h3>
        <span class="red-status uppercase">{{ election.status }}</span>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h3 class="font-normal text-md">{{ election.tier }}</h3>
        <p class="text-sm leading-loose">{{ election.date }}</p>
        <p class="text-sm leading-loose">
          {{ election.fromTime }} - {{ election.toTime }}
        </p>
        <p class="text-sm leading-loose">
          Number of Qualified Voters: {{ election.numQualified }}
        </p>
        <p class="text-sm leading-loose">
          Number of Voters: {{ election.numVotes }}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="space-y-4">
        <div
          class="cards py-5"
          v-for="candidates in election.candidates"
          :key="candidates.name"
        >
          <div>
            <h3>{{ candidates.name }}</h3>
            <div class="w-full bg-yellow-50 rounded-full dark:bg-gray-700">
              <div
                class="bg-yellow-300 text-xs font-medium text-blue-100 text-center p-0.5 leading-none rounded-full"
                v-bind:style="voteWidth"
              >
                {{ candidates.votes }}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
    <template #footer>
      <button @click="resultModal = false" class="black-button w-full mt-2">
        Close
      </button>
    </template>
  </modal>
</Teleport>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I saw another stack overflow that solved this problem, it didn't work properly before but I figured it out, here's my new implementation.

```
computed: {
        displayResults: function() {
            return this.elections.filter(election => election.status === 'completed')
        }
    },
```

and the HTML

```
<div v-for="result in displayResults" :key="result.id">
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not found `displayResult` data in your code, but generally if you want to show only some part of your data according to a special condition it is a good idea to use [v-if](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) in your template. So I changed some parts of your code as follows:

```html
<template>
<section>

      <div v-for="election in elections" :key="election.status">
      <!-- ############################ -->
      <!-- using "v-if" inside "v-for" for detecting desired status -->
      <!-- ############################ -->
        <div v-if="election.status =='completed'">
          <div>
            <h3 class="font-bold">Election Results</h3>
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="inline-flex space-x-2 align-middle">
              <h3 class="font-normal text-md">{{ election.title }}</h3>
              <span class="red-status uppercase">{{ election.status }}</span>
            </div>
            <div>
              <h3 class="font-normal text-md">{{ election.tier }}</h3>
              <p class="text-sm leading-loose">{{ election.date }}</p>
              <p class="text-sm leading-loose">
                {{ election.fromTime }} - {{ election.toTime }}
              </p>
              <p class="text-sm leading-loose">
                Number of Qualified Voters: {{ election.numQualified }}
              </p>
              <p class="text-sm leading-loose">
                Number of Voters: {{ election.numVotes }}
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="space-y-4">
              <div
                  class="cards py-5"
                  v-for="candidates in election.candidates"
                  :key="candidates.name"
              >
                <div>
                  <h3>{{ candidates.name }}</h3>
                  <div class="w-full bg-yellow-50 rounded-full dark:bg-gray-700">
                    <div
                        class="bg-yellow-300 text-xs font-medium text-blue-100 text-center p-0.5 leading-none rounded-full"
                    >
                      {{ candidates.votes }}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

</section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "electionsCompo",
  data() {
    return {
      elections: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "State Elections",
          tier: "Alpha State",
          fromTime: "09:00 pm",
          toTime: "11:00 am",
          date: "2020-06-01",
          status: "completed",
          numQualified: "200",
          numVotes: "157",
          candidates: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "John",
              votes: "80%",
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              // changed dekname to name
              name: "Fred",
              votes: "30%",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "City Elections",
          tier: "Beta City",
          fromTime: "09:00 pm",
          toTime: "11:00 am",
          date: "2020-06-01",
          status: "ongoing",
          numQualified: "120",
          numVotes: null,
          candidates: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "Chris",
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "Josh",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "President Elections",
          tier: "HQ",
          fromTime: "09:00 pm",
          toTime: "11:00 am",
          date: "2020-08-01",
          status: "pending",
          numQualified: "120",
          numVotes: null,
          candidates: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "Stone",
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "Ben",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    };
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

You can use this idea in your real `modal` component to see only the results of desired "status" in the template.

Comment: Thank you but this didn't work, instead, it changed the values of all the elections to 'completed' and displayed all of them. Apparently, v-if and v-for do not work well in the same elements.

Comment: @Lekins I did not use "v-if" and "v-for" on the **same** element. First I used ```v-for``` for looping through data and then I filtered data with the help of ```v-if```. I suggest that you paste my answer code in a **separate component** to test it and then use the **idea** for your own component.

Comment: Oh, I see, thank you for your help @hamid-davodi. This really helped.